# Composition of an operator and a bounded holomorphic mapping

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

If $f \in \mathcal{H}^\infty(U,F)$ is a bounded holomorphic mapping from an open subset of a complex Banach space $U$ into a complex Banach space $F$, then I know that $T \circ f = 0$, for all bounded linear operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(F,G)$, implies $f=0$.

Nevertheless, is this still true if we change the ideal of bounded linear operators by an arbitrary operator ideal $\mathcal{I}$? That is, $T \circ f = 0$, for all $T \in \mathcal{I}(F,G)$, implies $f=0$?

Comment: If you mean operator ideal in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_ideal) sense, then it should be true if $G\neq \{0\}$, because the ideal contains all finite range operators. The proof should be pretty mucht the same as the one for the first statement. What have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the notion of operator ideal in that sense. I believe that this is precisely the idea of the proof because the ideal of finite-rank operators is the smallest operator ideal. Therefore, it suffices to show the statement for that case.